# end-user denied authorization

Tags: access, login-errors, accesstoken

I'm trying to connect to Salesforce using Salesforce-CDP-jdbc driver and seems like I'm missing some grants and getting the error

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "end-user denied authorization"
}
```

I'm replicating the error with

```
curl --location --request POST "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=<ConsumerKey>&client_secret=<ConsumerSecret>&username=<myUser>&password=<MyPassword>"
```

This is responding correctly with

```
{
    "access_token": "<Token>",
    "instance_url": "https://myinstance-uat.sandbox.my.salesforce.com",
    "id": "https://test.salesforce.com/id/......",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "issued_at": "1705059664896",
    "signature": "M...="
}
```

and when I'm doing the call

```
curl --location --request POST "https://myinstance-uat.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/a360/token?subject_token_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Atoken-type%3Aaccess_token&grant_type=urn%3Asalesforce%3Agrant-type%3Aexternal%3Acdp&subject_token=<Token>"
```

I'm getting, the same as the Salesforce-CDP-jdbc driver the error:

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "end-user denied authorization"
}
```

I followed the steps from https://github.com/forcedotcom/Salesforce-CDP-jdbc to configure the app but now I'm stuck.

Any ideas on what else I have to configure?

Comment: Could anyone solved this problem? I faced with same error.

Comment: @Özgür My issue was that we don't have a CDP licence .. do you?